# How to check whether an element exists within a list?

Tags: python, tuples

I have tried this code of mine and it is not showing any errors also it is not showing any desired output..!!!

Code:

```
listx = [5, 10, 7, 4, 15, 3]
num=input("enter any number you want to search")
for i in listx :
    if num not in listx : continue
    else :    print("Element Found",i)
```

Comment: `num` is a string. Your list only contains ints. Also your loop is redundant: you only needed the if-statement.

Comment: It's generally not good form to write if/else statements like that.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the `in` operator:

```py
if int(num) in listx:
    print("Element Found")
```

The reason your code isn't working is because the elements inside the list are integers whereas the input returns a string: `"5" != 5`

Answer (score 0):

The `num` is never in the list, therefore the loop always executes `continue`. If you write

```
num=input("enter any number you want to search")
print(type(num))
```

and input a number, you will see `num`'s type is returned as 'str'. To use this input as a numeric value, simply modify to

```
num = int(input("enter any number you want to search"))
```

Also you can add a failsafe, where if the user inputs a non-numeric value, the code asks for a new input.

Answer (score 0):

You should typecast the input to integer value

```
listx = [5, 10, 7, 4, 15, 3]
num=int(input("enter any number you want to search"))
if(num in listx):
    print("Element Found",i)
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understood you want the index too!
there are two things wrong.

1. you used an Array List not a tuple, the code should work either way
2. Your input comes as a string not an integer

Here's how to fix them, will not return Index of the value

```
tuple = (5, 10, 7, 4, 15, 3)
num = int(input("input ? ")) # the int function makes input() an integer
if num in list: print('Found!') # you don't need a for loop here
```

This will return the Index of the value:

```
for i in range(len(tuple)):
    if num not in tuple: print("Not Found"),  break # for efficiency
    if num == tuple[i]: print( 'Found at Index', i)
```

The difference between Array Lists and tuples are that tuples cannot change values, but an Array List can

this will produce an error

```
tuple[1] = "some value"
```

but this won't, given that the ArrayList variable exists

```
ArrayList[1] = "some value"
```